# SMS scheduling with Timer in Android

Tags: java, android, timer, schedule

i'm new to Android and Java, and im playing a bit with a Timer in Android. My purpose is to schedule the sending of an sms. So, i use a timer to delay the time when sending the sms. Everything works fine, no errors or so on, but my problem is that the timer doesn't wait with sending sms when i execute my app on android, so it is beeing send directly after pressing the "send" button and then processing without waiting (something similar to a endless loop). Hoping someone can help:

```
public class SendMessageActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setText("Hallo");

            final Timer mytimer = new Timer(true);

            final TimerTask mytask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sms.sendTextMessage(phone, "", "Hi Droide!",
                            null, null);
                }
            };

            mytimer.schedule(mytask, 1000L, 3000L);

            final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mytimer.cancel();
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 mytimer.schedule(mytask, 1000L, 3000L);
```

That means, delay before the first execution is 1 second and the amount of time between subsequent executions is 3 seconds.

If you want to increase the delay use,
mytimer.schedule(mytask, 60000L, 180000L); // (1min, 3min)

Comment: -.- What we've learned of this: programing after university won't be very successful ;-) Thank's a lot, that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this method

```
public void schedule (TimerTask task, Date when)
```

The second parameters define the date to send the message, I think it's the wrong method called in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but this doesn't solve my problem... I think my error must be something else, because in my opinion it won't matter whether i use `public void schedule (TimerTask task, Date when)` or `public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` because it has the same effect...